# Wordpress Admin form custom $_POST request

Tags: php, wordpress, request, admin

I am working on a admin page in Wordpress where I save my custom settings. Now I want to add a submit button where I can insert some pages at once with.

I cannot submit like this in my Wordpress admin. I did a simple test by echoing out 'test' after the submit but I got no output. Can someone help me with this.

This is my code:

```
<?php function stn_gen_settings() { ?>

    <form method="post" action="options.php">

        <div class="stn_divide">

            <fieldset>

                <h3><?php _e( 'Set account pages' ); ?></h3>

                <?php 
                // Insert account pages
                if( isset( $_POST['set_account_pages'] ) ) {

                    echo 'test';

                    $account_page = array(
                        'post_title'    => 'Test page',
                        'post_content'  => '[test_shortcode]',
                        'post_type' => 'account',
                    );

                    $page_id = wp_insert_post( $account_page );
                }
                ?> 

                <?php submit_button( __( 'Set account pages' ), 'secondary', 'set_account_pages', $wrap, $other_attributes ) ?>

            </fieldset>

        </div><!--End stn_divide-->


    </form>

<?php } 

add_menu_page( '639Listings', '639Listings', 'manage_options', 'stn_general', 'stn_gen_settings' );
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issues with your code:

1) Add the menu page through the hook `admin_menu`:

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'stn_gen_page' ); 

function stn_gen_page
{
    add_menu_page( 
        '639Listings', 
        '639Listings', 
        'manage_options', 
        'stn_general', 
        'stn_gen_settings' 
    );
}
```

2) Leave the form action empty, `options.php` is only for special cases:

```
<form method="post" action="">
```

3) You pasted the `submit_button()` function without adjusting the parameters, you don't have and don't need `$wrap` and `$other_attributes`, [read the docs](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/submit_button) for details:

```
<?php submit_button( __( 'Set account pages' ), 'secondary', 'set_account_pages' ) ?>
```

After that, the submit is successful, echoing `test` and creating the post.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I need `options.php` there because I have some other options which I save with that form. What should I do now? Make a new admin page for this feature, or make a new form on this page without the action?

Comment: You can display (and modify) those specific options in your plugin page. Will try to find an example, but it's basic stuff with `<input>`, `$_POST`, `get_option` and `update_option`.

Comment: No, cannot locate the example, but you'll find something [inside this search query](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=%2Badmin_menu+%2Bget_option+is%3Aa)

Comment: Yeah I know. I save the options already, but my question how I can combine the forms which needed the `action="options.php"` and the form which don't need it. I have fixed it by using 2 form on one plugin page now, and that works.

Comment: Ok, but that's not stated in your original post... I'm afraid we are running into a [chameleon question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions?) ;)